# How to get integers and different values from one form to another?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, integer

I made a Math Quiz program by following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492172%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I wanted to add a debug menu to change different things such as **stop the timer of Form1 by using a button on the debugForm**. I got the button and the form set up but I am not sure how to import integers such as:

```
int TimeLeft

into debugForm for use in Form1.
```

[Here is my code that I got so far.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/02f109001ab371ba45d2)

I'm not sure where to start so I need help and if you need me to clarify something then just ask. Thanks!

**Edit :**

Sorry for not being really clear.
**My question is :** How do I take integers from one form and put them in another and have them being recognized?

Comment: This is setup to look more like a project than a question.

Comment: Where do you want to import the integer from? Do you want `TimeLeft` to represent the time left, but you don't know how to do it?

Comment: TimeLeft represents the time left in Form1 successfully but I am not sure how to get TimeLeft to be recognized in debugForm.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your `debugForm` class:

```
private int m_timeLeft;
public int TimeLeft
{
    get
    {
        return m_timeLeft;
    }
    set
    {
        m_timeLeft = value;
        // some other actions if necessary
    }
}
```

Now, you can access this property from your `Form1`:

```
private void makeMenu(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    debugForm form = new debugForm();
    form.TimeLeft = this.TimeLeft;
    form.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare the integers and any other members/fields public so you can access them from any form (class). By not specifying the access modifier the members are by default private so you cannot access them from anywhere else.

EDIT:

Ok here is a quick example of member access :

First you declare your form (which is a class)

```
public class FormaA :Form 
{ 
      public int myFirstInteger = 100; //the public keyword in front of it does all the job 
      public int mySecondInteger = 50; //second integer declaration
}
```

Now lets declare another form

```
 public class FormB : Form {    

    //this is the FormB constructor
    //if you don't declare one C# will declare one for you
    public FormB()
    {
        //you have access to the members in the CONSTRUCTOR
        int myFormAInteger = formA.myFirstInteger; //Whoaallllaaaa ! magic ! you have acces to the member
        int myFormASecondInteger = formA.mySecondInteger ; //the second integer
    }
```

}

But remeber **ANY CHANGES ON THE FIRST FORM WILL NOT BE UPDATED IN THE SECOND FORM** you have to use a **REFERENCE** to gain access to the updated value.

Hope this helps

Consider reading a book (Deitel Beginning C# is a very great book and with some great examples and also Wrox Beginning Visual C# 2010 /2012 is a very good read)
Posting your questions here is useful but try to tackle with the problem yourself before turning to help.

Comment: I tried putting Public infront of Int but it didn't seem to do much. How would I go about doing this? I just starting programming a couple of days ago so I am not really good at anything yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the constructor for debugform you can pass any values you need when you declare the new form:

```
Form 2 Code
-------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Math_Quiz
{
    public partial class debugForm : Form
    {
        public debugForm(int value1, string value2)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //set the values to local variables.
        }

        private void timeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}


private void makeMenu(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    debugForm form = new debugForm(intvalue, stringvalue);
    form.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I have found to pass int, and string values from one for to the next is:

```
 private void gameStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
        int numberOfPlayers = 10;

        multiplayerGame y = new multiplayerGame(numberOfPlayers, machineName);// multiplayerGame is the next form, and y is just a very simple variable the new form plus variables that are being passed is assigned to
                this.Hide();();// hides this (current) form
                y.ShowDialog();//here is where the variable y is used with .ShowDialog to make your program open the new form
        }
    }
```

This above code is an example from one of my programs, and is what I have used in my form passing the variable I want to use in my next form. In the next form you need to add the following code for the variable to be seen and assigned to a usable variable for that entire form.

```
 public partial class multiplayerGame : Form
{
    private int numPlayers;// This is the variable that will be used on this form for the int variable being passed 
    private string myPcName; ;// This is the variable that will be used on this form for the string variable being passed   
}
```

Next in the section your program initializes everything you need to allow the variable from form1 to pass into the new form, and assign it to the variable made for the new form. in my example this is multiplayerGame.

```
public multiplayerGame(int numberOfPlayers, string machineName)// int so the new form knows your passing an int, then the name of your variable same goes for the string variable
    {
        this.myPcName = machineName;// here you assign the private string created above for this form to equal the string variable being passed into this from form the previous form
        this.numPlayers = numberOfPlayers; // here you assign the private int created above for this form to equal the int variable being passed into this from form the previous form
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then you will have a variable can used that will be recognized and will already have the values set from the previous form  as soon as your second from loads. Only thing left at this point is to use your variables where they are needed.